# Cloudbees - Received 500 error after deployment

Tags: tomcat, servlets, cloudbees

I have developed a JAVA (JDK1.7) servlet web application.  I have deployed this using Tomcat locally.  No issues. The application is running fine locally.

I have imported the WAR file from eclipse.
I have now deployed the WAR into cloudbees. I have installed the cloud SDK.  I have deployed it using the below command.  Deployment was successful.

When executing the application, the client pages are displayed correctly. When selecting the option, the method call gives the below error.  It is saying `class not found` for the method call.  This method is packaged/deployed already.  It is working fine locally.
Does Cloudbee expect to keep the external jars in a specific folder?
Appreciate your help

```
type Exception report
message Servlet execution threw an exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vmware/vim25/mo/ManagedEntity
```

Thanks, Raje

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues:

#### Unrelated boot issue

Check the log files from the app starting in the RUN console. Look for any errors, resolve and redeploy.

#### Class not deployed

It would be a good idea to confirm that you are packaging your WAR correctly within the CloudBees environment.

From the RUN console download the deployed WAR file and unpack it to confirm that the `com/vmware/vim25/mo/ManagedEntity` class is contained in a jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` area or as a class file in `WEB-INF/classes`.